# Proving that $K:l_2 \to l_2$ is a compact self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I need to prove the following:

> Let $a = (a_j)$ be a real sequence from $c_0$ (Banach space of sequences converging to 0) and let X = $l_2$ be a space of complex sequences $(x_j)$ with $\|x\| = (\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j|^2)^\frac{1}{2}<\infty$. Define $(Kx)_j = a_jx_j$. Show that $K:X\to X$ is a compact operator.

As I understand, a compact operator is a one whereby for any bounded set $B \in X$, any sequence in $K(B)$ has a convergent subsequence. So let $B$ be bounded and $(y_j) = (x_n)^j$ be a sequence of sequences in $K(B)$. Then we need to find $(y_{j_k})$ a subsequence of $(y_j)$ which converges. But I am not sure how to do this; perhaps we need to extract the compactness from compactness in $\mathbb{C}$?

As for the self-adjoint part of the question, I could really do with a hint here, too.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Since you're on a Hilbert space, you could use the alternative definition for a compact operator, which is an operator that is a limit of finite rank operators.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this definition; what is a finite rank operator? @CameronWilliams

Comment: Ack. It's basically a limit of matrices where the entries go to zero sufficiently fast, but if you don't have that definition, you have to do it the hard (and long) way.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, ah, I can see how that would be helpful. But yes, unfortunately I have to do it the long and hard way. Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a sequence of vectors $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for which $\|x_n \| \le M$. Using the Cantor diagonalization process, you can replace $\{ x_n \}$ with a subsequence such that $\lim_k (x_{n_k})_j$ converges for all $j$. So, without loss of generality, assume that $\lim_{n} (x_n)_j$ converges for each $j$. And let $A$ be a constant such that $|a_j| \le A$ for all $j$. Then,
\begin{align}
     \|K x_{n}-Kx_{n+m} \|^2 & = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_j|^2|(x_n)_j-(x_{n+m})_j|^2 \\
   & \le A\sum_{j=1}^{N}|(x_n)_j-(x_{n+m})_j|^2
     +\sup_{j > N}|a_j|^2\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|(x_n)_j-(x_{n+m})_j|^2 \\
    & \le A\sum_{j=1}^{N}|(x_n)_j-(x_{n+m})_j|^2+4M^2\sup_{j > N}|a_j|^2
\end{align}
Given $\epsilon > 0$, you can choose $N$ large enough that $4M^2\sup_{j > N}|a_j|^2 < \epsilon/2$. Then you can choose $n$ large enough such that, for this fixed $N$, you have $A\sum_{j=1}^{N}|(x_n)_j-(x_{n+m})_j|^2 < \epsilon/2$ because the coordinate sequences converge. It follows that $\{ Kx_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence and, hence converges.

Comment: Why for $\{x_n\}$, there is a subsequence such that $\lim_j (x_{n_k})_j$ converges?   Since $\lVert x_n \rVert \leq M$, then $\sum_j  |(x_n)_j|^2 \leq M^2$ and hence $\lim_j (x_n)_j =0$ for all $x_n$?

Comment: Oh I thought what you mean in your answer $\lVert x_n \rVert \leq M$ is $(\sum_j |(x_n)_j|^2)^{1/2}\leq M$, since the OP said that the norm on $\ell^2$ is defined to be this.

Comment: @userHasNoNumber : I had mixed $j$ and $k$ in some of the limits, and just fixed that. Take another look.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. How did you deduce that every $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence such that $\lim_k (x_{n_k})_j$ converges for all $j$?

Comment: @userHasNoNumber : $|(x_n)_j| \le \|x_n\| \le M$. So you can find a subsequence $x_{n_{k_1}}$ such that $(x_{n_{k_1}})_1$ converges. Then you can choose $\{ x_{n_{{k_1}_{k_2}}}\}$ that converges in the first and second coordinate. Etc.. Then by the Cantor diagonalization process, there is a subsequence $\{ x_{n_{k}}\}$ so that $(x_{n_{k}})_j$ converges for all $j$.